# Não consigo Colocar background-color e Outline

Tags: html, css

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e estou com os seguintes problemas:

1. Não consigo preencher o espaço em branco que se encontra por cima do título "**Ordenar Pesquisa**" usando o `background-color` aplicado ao mesmo.
2. Não consigo colocar uma linha `outline: 1px solid #E0E0DA;` e aplicar a propriedade `padding` entre as categorias da lista, na classe `.ordena`.

Aqui segue o código e um *screenshot* do mesmo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.conteudo_ordenar{
    border:1px solid #E0E0DA;
    border-top: 3px solid #00008B;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00008B;
    height: 200px;
}
.titulo_ordenar {
    background-color: #00008B;
    color:White;
    text-align: center;
}
.orderna {
    outline: 1px solid #E0E0DA;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="conteudo_ordenar">
        <h3 class="titulo_ordenar">Ordenar Pesquisa</h3>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Marca</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Tamanho</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Cor</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Faixa De Preço</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Não estas a conseguir "preencher" o espaço por cima do título por causa dos [estilos padrão do Navegador](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp).
2. Não estás a conseguir aplicar estilos aos items da 'lista' porque o selector está com um erro tipográfico, em vez de estar `ordena` está `orderna` no código CSS.

```css
.conteudo_ordenar {
    border:1px solid #E0E0DA;
    border-top: 3px solid #00008B;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00008B;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto; /* isto para evitar o conteúdo transborde o "container", por causa da altura limite de "200px height" definido acima */
}
.titulo_ordenar {
    background-color: #00008B;
    color:White;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0; /* Aplica um reset à margem automática do título atribuída pelo Navegador */
}
.ordena {
    outline: 1px solid #E0E0DA;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="conteudo_ordenar">
        <h3 class="titulo_ordenar">Ordenar Pesquisa</h3>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Marca</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Tamanho</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Cor</p>
        <p class="ordena"><span class="caret"></span> Faixa De Preço</p>
    </div>
</div>
```